# How to connect & deactivate Azure Active Directory through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

While trying to connect to Azure AD with cmdlets Connect-MsolService it prompts for credentials but I am a bit confuse which credentials I have to provide than through cmdlets Get-Credentials I have got the credentials but that also didn't work.

However my aim is to connect to Azure AD through powershell & also activate/deactivate or start/stop Azure AD through powershell...Please put some light on this or provide some help...

Answer (score 1):

When you use the PowerShell and `Connect-MsolService` you have to provide the target directory admin account - an account with full administrative permissions on the Directory tenant. And currently you cannot just provide credentials, you have to use that window that prompts for credentials.

However I don't really understand what you mean by `start/stop Azure AD`. Azure AD is a cloud service that runs constantly. You cannot start or stop it. You have it. You may disable user accounts in it, but you certainly cannot `stop` the service. If you better describe your question it will be easier to help you!

Comment: ,I have a question. When i use my live Id( the one i use at https://manage.windowsazure.com)..the error is thrown which says "user name or password is incorrect" please can you help what i am doing wrong.?

Comment: i ended up creating another admin user so that it matched format user@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com, earlier i was using my windows live user name, which was also a WAAD admin user.

Comment: You have to use an account that is created inside Azure AD (As Pointed out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485364/powershell-connecting-to-azure-active-directory-using-microsoft-account). Microsoft Account is currently not supported.