# PowerShell - Connecting to Azure Active Directory using Microsoft Account

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure subscription where the subscription administrator account is a Microsoft Account. I then added another Microsoft Account as a co-administrator. I'm told that when I add a co-administrator, it gets added to my subscription's default AD as a `Guest` user. What I really want to accomplish is change the user type from `Guest` to `Member`. For this, I am advised to use Azure AD PowerShell and this is where I am struggling.

I've already installed related PS Modules (based on this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj151815.aspx).

So here's what I am doing:

First, this is the command I am issuing:

```
$msolcred = get-credential
```

I get prompted for entering my credentials which I provide and then I run the following command:

```
connect-msolservice -credential $msolcred
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
connect-msolservice : The user name or password is incorrect. Verify your user name, and then type your password again.
At line:1 char:1
+ connect-msolservice -Credential $cred -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 0x80048821,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolService
```

I even tried putting the username as `domainname.onmicrosoft.com\username` but still get the same result.

So my questions are:

- Is it even possible to connect to Azure AD via PowerShell using Microsoft Account?
- If it is possible, then how should I specify the username? I have tried both `username` as well as `domainname\username` and I got the same error.
- If it is not possible, then what's the alternate solution? Should I just create a user in that AD and put that user in a role that has permission to manage users (as this is what I want to do)?

Any insights regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(Updated 2018-04-23 to clarify how to do this with AzureAD (v2) module.)

The [AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) (v2) PowerShell module accepts the `‑TenantId` parameter in [`Connect‑AzureAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread?view=azureadps-2.0), which can be either the Guid tenant ID, or any verified domain name in the Azure AD tenant. Doing so will allow you to sign in using an external account (e.g. you personal Microsoft account, or a work or school account from another Azure AD tenant, as long as this account was previously invited into the tenant):

```powershell
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId "contoso.com"
```

The [MSOnline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-msonlinev1?view=azureadps-1.0) (v1) module does not have an equivalent parameter, but it does accept `‑AdGraphAccessToken` and `‑MsGraphAccessToken`, which are access tokens to the Azure AD Graph API (`https://graph.windows.net`) and the Microsoft Graph API (`https://graph.microsoft.com`), respectively. Though you can use ADAL (for example) to obtain these access tokens for your specific tenant (which allows you to use external users), it's probably simpler to just create a "local" account to your Azure AD tenant for this.

<strike>Signing in to AAD PowerShell with a Microsoft Account is not currently supported. Your approach (make a new user that is "native" to the directory) is the way to go.</strike>

Comment: Thanks. IMHO, `connect-msolservice` should have a parameter where I can specify target AD for authentication purpose. This would make this possible.

Comment: There's a little bit more to it than this, but the idea is on the right track. You could vote/add requests on the AAD feedback site. This one is related to [this](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/6920135-enable-management-of-secondary-directories-using), [this](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/6438596-fix-problem-with-connect-msolservice-and-multi-fac), and [this](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/6998686-update-the-azure-active-directory-powershell-modul) ones.

Comment: Note that Microsoft are in the process of updating the PS addon to use browser-based authentication which should support MFA and other options.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulwu/archive/2015/10/09/mfa-support-for-windows-azure-active-directory-powershell-module.aspx

But it still doesn't seem to work on my Microsoft account.

Comment: October 2016 and you still can't use a Microsoft Account to manage AD :(  they do have the web authentication in place, but there's no option to switch out from a Corporate (or school) account.

Answer (score 4):

For those that run across this question in the future, the previous answer still appears to be correct.  Basically, you have to create a new account that is native to the directory.  This account can be used to login when running connect-msolservice in PowerShell, and then you can run set-msoluser to convert the user from "Guest" to "Member".

The following blog post has detailed step-by-step directions to do this.  Note that you need to follow the Appendix first if your Global Admin account is not a work or school account.  Also, I've added a few important details in the Comments section of the blog post.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dstfs/2015/12/23/issues-with-azure-active-directory-guest-users-in-aad-backed-visual-studio-team-services-accounts/

For reference, a similar problem and resolution using set-msoluser can be found in this forum post:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/469baa2d-7ff1-4e17-a8f0-f257cbdbf50b/cannot-see-the-active-directory-item-in-the-azure-portal?forum=WindowsAzureAD