# Why as a co-administrator of a subscription am I unable to edit the Active Directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

A customer made me a co-administrator of his Azure subscription. However, I am unable to edit his Active Directory, ie add/edit users, create applications, etc.

Why can't I access that? I'm thinking perhaps the Subscription is owned by the AD and not the other way around.

What do each of the role levels in AD allow? There's

- Global Admin
- Billing Admin
- Service Admin
- User Admin
- Password Admin

Comment: Permissions around Active Directory accounts don't fall in line exactly with Azure subscription administrators. There is some history reasons  and multiple systems merging together reasons as well (for example, with VSO). It's a bit messy, unfortunately, since they both maintain their own sets of permissions.

Comment: 2 questions: 1) Do you see your customer's AD in the list of ADs when you login into Azure Portal? and 2) I'm guessing that you use your Microsoft Account to login into Azure Portal and the same account is made co-admin. Is this correct?

Comment: 1) yes I see the directory but when I click on User/Groups etc it is says "You do not have permission to access these resources.. 2) yes, my Microsoft Account.

Comment: Description of the different Azure AD roles: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn468213.aspx

Comment: Fun, you need to be a "Global Admin" just to create an RmADApplication within your subscription, which is needed for managing individual Azure resources outside of the CLI/cmdlets. Azure is so awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was that I needed to be set up as a Global Administrator in the Azure AD domain.

Comment: In my case I asked the AD subscription admin to make me global admin in the AD, where I am co-admin, and I am still unable to edit the directory. The strange thing is that the Default Directory ID for me, when I log in to the subscription, is a different Default Directory ID than for him, when he logs in to the same subscription.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, global admin + co-admin is not enough to be able to access the AD directory settings of another people. This should not be an accepted answer.

Comment: This is how I resolved my issue. It is the answer that solved it for me, so that's why it is the accepted answer. I'm not sure what settings you can't access as a Global admin. All that you shouldn't be able to access is subscription settings like billing info, etc.

Answer (score 10):

I believe the primary reason for this error is because when a co-admin with Microsoft account is added to a subscription, it gets added into the subscription AD as `Guest` user type. In order for you to get access to that AD so that you can perform the operations on the AD, you user type needs to be changed to `Member` from `Guest`. I had exact same issue with one of the users of our product and the steps described below solved the problem.

To change the user type, one would need to use AD PowerShell Cmdlets. The process is rather convoluted and needs to be done by your customer.

1. First, check with your customer if they themselves are using Microsoft Account for signing in into the portal. If they are, then they would need to create a user in their Azure AD. Please see this thread for why this is needed: [PowerShell - Connecting to Azure Active Directory using Microsoft Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485364/powershell-connecting-to-azure-active-directory-using-microsoft-account).
2. Next, they would need to sign in using this user account because one would need to change user password on the 1st login.
3. Install AD Modules. You may find these links useful for that purpose: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj151815.aspx#bkmk_installmodule, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41950 (Please choose 64 bit version) and http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=236297.
4. Launch PowerShell and execute the following commands:

.

```
$cred = Get-Credential  #In the window that shows up, please specify the local AD user credentials.

connect-msolservice -Credential $cred

(Get-MsolUser -SearchString "your microsoft account email address").UserType #This should output "Guest". If it doesn’t, please stop and do not proceed further as there might be some other issue.

(Get-MsolUser -SearchString "your microsoft account email address") | Set-MsolUser -UserType Member

(Get-MsolUser -SearchString "your microsoft account email address").UserType #This should now output "Member"
```

If somehow the problem still persists, ask your customer to login into the portal, delete your user record from AD users list and add it again. That should also take care of this problem.

Comment: I was added to his Azure AD first. I think the issue is I am set as Service Admin and not Global Admin. I'm having him change me to Global Admin to see if that is the issue.

Comment: @Gaurav - this is awesome! Feels hackish and dirty, but it works! One interesting thing, PowerShell intelli-sense doesn't show `-UserType` for `Set-MsolUser`, however, it works!

Answer (score 2):

Both answers above seem to be correct in it's own way.

As a starter subscription administrator does not automatically make you an Azure AD administrator. You'd need explicit role grant on the target Azure AD.

Second aspect is the type of the account used. If it's in current Azure AD or Microsoft Live account all is well. 
In case that account is part of an external Azure AD, by default user type is  "Guest"(can login, but cannot control event if assigned "Global admin"). Therefore PowerShell commands highlighted above should be executed to change user type to "Member".

Some more helpful info can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dstfs/2015/12/23/issues-with-azure-active-directory-guest-users-in-aad-backed-visual-studio-team-services-accounts/) (it is mentioned as a Visual Studio Team Services issue, but actually applies to most Azure related services).

Comment: It wasn't the AD I wanted to administer, I needed the ability to create Web Site and Mobile apps, configure them, etc. withing their subscription.  I didn't think I needed to be a global admin for that, since I didn't need to be able to add/edit users in the AD, my client would be the one doing that.

Comment: In such case having your user added to the target Azure AD would be sufficient. Followed by co-administrator assignment.