# Access issue on Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We've got a subscription with two admins (global admin on AD). Each of them have created a new B2C blade associated with the subscription.

Both can see the both B2C instances under resource list, however each person can only see the B2C blade which is created by himself/herself and gets Unauthorized error when navigating to the instance created by other person.

The error text is:

> User authorization failed. You must be a Global Administrator in "GUID" in order to access this functionality. If you created this B2C directory just now, please try again after couple of minutes. Read the following article to learn more.

Things that I've tried:

- Adding both users as global administrator on AD instance and also on both B2C instances.
- Adding both users as subscription owners

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty weird. Adding users as subscription owners will not work though since subscription roles are not related to AAD roles.

Comment: @Yaser have you found a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @user1715925  your user should be added as a guest user to the B2C. Then make it admin. Also don’t forget to link the B2C to subscription

Answer (score -1):

Being a global administrator in the B2C instance/tenant is the only thing that matters. You can add both users as global administrators in the B2C tenants by going to the "Users and Groups" blades, and adding a user. This will send an invitation email to the user, which needs to be accepted. Once the invitation is accepted, you can mark the user as a global administrator by going back to the "Users and Groups" menu in the Azure AD B2C.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380869/why-as-a-co-administrator-of-a-subscription-am-i-unable-to-edit-the-active-direc/30381918#30381918