# Not able to add new user in VSTS

Tags: active-directory, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am added to project collection administrator group in VSTS. Still not able to add a new user. I am added using my official email ID i.e. Microsoft work account.

Its says

> Guest users are not allowed to perform this action.

I saw the reason on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380869/why-as-a-co-administrator-of-a-subscription-am-i-unable-to-edit-the-active-direc)

> I believe the primary reason for this error is because when a co-admin
>   with Microsoft account is added to a subscription, it gets added into
>   the subscription AD as Guest user type.

but since it is very old thread i like to know if there is an easy way to get myself ability to add new user or basically manage VSTS on behalf of client. I hate requesting client to add a new user in team. Also he is not tech savvy so I would like suggest him a simple solution (running Powershell might be annoying for him).

Comment: When you look at your self as a user in the list of users, and click change access level in context menu, what are your access level?

Comment: I am assigned Basic access level at account level. I am also Project Collection Administrators.

Answer (score 1):

You are inviting users from outside directory. The user will be able to access the account and its resources, so you need the enough permission to add new user to the AD, but you are the Guest user, so it throws Guest Users are not allowed to perform this action.

You need to contact to the corresponding user (e.g. AD admin) to add users to AD or grant the enough role and permission to you to add user to AD.

No easy way to do this, because it is related to security.

Comment: "grant the enough role and permission to you to add user to AD." That's exactly my question. What role or permission should I get to be able to add new users. I guess its not in VSTS but at AD level. I need to guide client for action he has to take to give me correct rights.

Comment: Based on this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-assign-admin-roles-azure-portal#available-roles), you can try it with User Account Administrator role.